# Node.js / Nginx : Request timesout at Nginx before processing finishes at node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, npm

I have a `Nginx/Node.js` server setup. The basic process is that I upload a file to `nginx` from a browser which forwards it to `node.js`. `Node.js` processes the file and returns an output to the browser via `nginx`.

While it works fine for most of the files, it crashes when the uploaded file is too large. After receiving a file my node starts processing on the file but before the node finishes its process the request times out at nginx. The node keeps on running and successfully completes the process but it is of no use to me.

What can I do to solve my problem? Increase the nginx timeout (but to what limit)? Try to speed up my process at node (i am already trying that but i can only do that upto some extent)? Try using node module `socket.io` (I don't know how but i am not even sure whether it will work)?

Thnx in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Your node process shouldn't wait for the processing to be done until it returns the response. Process the files in background workers by queuing it. You could even go one step further and use direct upload to something like Amazon S3 without touching your stack at all and then queue the file for processing.

Decoupling is **the** solution. There are just different ways to implement it.

Edit:

Here's a concrete example of I handle file uploads.

1. The node server instance stores the file in S3 using https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js
2. I then queue a `processing` command using https://github.com/learnboost/kue (other popular options include RabbitMQ)
3. The server responds with a success message.
4. Now as soon as it's idling, a second process (the worker) fetches the file from S3 and processes it.
5. On the client you can poll the current processing state (and even a progress bar, if your worker is able to calculate and store a progress) and tell the user when it's done. You can optionally use something like socket.io instead of polling and allow both the server process and the worker process to push messages to the client (again, this could be decoupled by using something like redis pub/sub or RabbitMQ and store the messages which a third "chat" process send out to the clients).

Comment: could you cite an example of decoupling which u think i can use here in my case? The output from my node is a html page which I present in the browser.